# Redirect https://subdomain to https://subdomain.domain.tld

Tags: apache-httpd, url

I am trying to fix a setup where people accessed a site via `https://subdomain` but we have a proper SSL cert for `https://subdomain.domain.tld`.

I am trying to force redirect to `https://subdomain.domain.tld` when people navigate to the old URL.

I've tried all sort of variations to no avail. Currently my thinking was something like below:

Note: This seems to work for http --> https but not http(S).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.domain.tld
  ServerAlias subdomain
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://subdomain.domain.tld:443/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName subdomain
  Redirect https://subdomain  https://subdomain.domain.tld:443/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName subdomain.domain.tld

  ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: To redirect everything use `Redirect / https://subdomain.domain.tld/` (HTTP 302) or `Redirect permanent / https://subdomain.domain.tld/` (HTTP 301).
You don't need to add the port number `:443` in both examples as this is the default https port. You could also change the `RewriteRule` to a `Redirect` in your first vhost and remove `RewriteEngine On`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you NEED to have the SSL for both sites if you want to redirect https --> https. I was able to redirect using a separate virtual-host and the old SSL cert which was self-signed to the new public one, but any users without the CA for the self-signed cert will not get redirected.